# CodeIgniter Loading Database Unnecessarily?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Just started using CodeIgniter, loving it.

Having enabled the database to be one of the libraries to be loaded. I noticed that on pages that I don't even use the database (static pages). CI complains:

> A Database Error Occurred Unable to
>   connect to your database server using
>   the provided settings.

The error is not a problem as I haven't supplied the correct username/password. The problem is, would CI try to connect to the database on every page load even though my application doesn't require it on that page or am I missing something?

Or am I missing the point of AutoLoad?

Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autoload in Code Igniter tells the system to load a particular library at each page load. If you have static pages that don't require the database (and you don't want a connection to be made when they are loaded), then you need to stop the database from being autoloaded. You'll also need to manually load the database library on non-static pages where a db connection is necessary.

Comment: I see. I am guessing applications that need the database on every page exist since they are the only ones able to make good use of AutoLoad? Or are there other scenarios?

Comment: Most applications out there will require the database on each and every page for some reason or another. A lot of applications store the navigation in the database, which is generally on every page. Even static-like pages can be stored as text entries in a table for easy alteration via a CMS or some such management system.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the explanation. A simple question I know, but I am complete noob. :)